# How do I compile a C++ file to WebAssembly?

Tags: c++, webassembly

Suppose I have a simple, self-contained C++ file (`math.cpp`) like this:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

How would I compile it to WebAssembly (`math.wasm`)?

Note: I am using the Clang tool-chain.

Answer (score 39):

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/yurydelendik/4eeff8248aeb14ce763e) to be very helpful.

Basically, this are the steps:

1. (build llvm and clang 5.0.0 or above with `-DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=WebAssembly`)
2. Compile the .cpp soure to llvm bitcode with clang:

   `clang -emit-llvm --target=wasm32 -Oz math.cpp -c -o math.bc`
3. Compile the bitcode to s-assembly:

   `llc -asm-verbose=false -o math.s math.bc`
4. Use [binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen)'s s2wasm tool to create a .wast file

   `s2wasm math.s > math.wast`
5. Use [WABT](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt)'s wast2wasm tool to translate the textual .wast file into binary .wasm:

   `wast2wasm -o math.wasm math.wast`

Some of the steps feel redundant but I have not yet found a tool that allows shortcuts. (It would be nice if llc could compile directly to .wasm, or if s2wasm actually created binary .wasm files as the name suggests.) Anyway, once you got the toolchain running it's relatively painless. Note, however, that there are no C or C++ standard libraries for web assembly yet.

Alternatively, if you need the .wasm file just for trying out stuff you can get away without all the toolchain trouble. Browse to https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/, [paste in your C/C++ code](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/?state=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22showGutter%22%3Atrue%2C%22showConsole%22%3Atrue%2C%22showOptions%22%3Atrue%2C%22autoCompile%22%3Atrue%2C%22showLLVM%22%3Afalse%2C%22darkMode%22%3Atrue%2C%22fastMath%22%3Afalse%2C%22noInline%22%3Afalse%2C%22noRTTI%22%3Afalse%2C%22noExceptions%22%3Afalse%2C%22cleanWast%22%3Afalse%2C%22wasmBaseline%22%3Afalse%2C%22dialect%22%3A%22C%2B%2B11%22%2C%22optimizationLevel%22%3A%22s%22%7D%2C%22source%22%3A%22int%20add(int%20x%2C%20int%20y)%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20return%20x%20%2B%20y%3B%5Cr%5Cn%7D%22%7D), and download the compiled .wasm file.

---

Thank you @noontz and @LB-- for pointing out that

> Actually as the comments in the gist suggest you can skip binaryen and compile straight to wasm from Clang/LLVM. I'm currently using the following command line for C++ :
>
> ```
> clang++ test.cpp -ObjC++ --compile --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm \ 
>         --optimize=3 --output test.wasm
> ```

Comment: Actually as the comments in the gist suggest you can skip binaryen and compile straight to wasm from Clang/LLVM.  I'm currently using the following command line for C++ : `clang++ test.cpp -ObjC++ --compile --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm --optimize=3 --output test.wasm`

Comment: @noontz Uh, nice.. looks like it's worth to read gist comments after all ;) I will edit this into the answer if someone can independently confirm this works (or after I've managed to try it).

Comment: I can confirm that noontz' command works to generate a .wasm file with LLVM 7, but I haven't tried running it yet.

Comment: Thank you @LB--. I take your comment and the upvotes on noontz's as verification. Unfortunately, I have not come around to try it myself :)

Comment: But how do you run this code? I keep getting an error `TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object`

Answer (score 16):

[Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) comes with everything you will need to compile a C++ file to wasm. Emscripten also has an [SDK](https://github.com/juj/emsdk) that makes life easy when it comes to installing all the necessary tools.

By default, however, Emscripten will add some framework code to your wasm file as well as generate some html and javascript.

It is possible to create a minimal wasm file with Emscripten that doesn't include any framework code, javascript, or html. Using options `-s SIDE_MODULE=1 -Oz -s ONLY_MY_CODE=1` while compiling with `emcc` or `em++` will give you a minimal wasm file.

The following command would export a minimal wasm file using your examples and Emscripten:

`em++ math.cpp -o math.wasm -Oz -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -s WASM=1 -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_add']" -s ONLY_MY_CODE=1`

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying this: `Assigning a non-existent settings attribute "WASM"`

Comment: I'm getting "dyncall undefined". I'm so done with emscripten, it's no longer a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 10):

As of 2019, Clang (8) supports webassembly out of the box. Here is a repository that contains everything needed to compile, link and run a simple .wasm file.

https://github.com/PetterS/clang-wasm

Comment: One thing to note is this will work only for small code.

Comment: Couldn't run this on macOS (10.15.6) - same issues as the ones already filed in the repo.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the easiest way to compile C and C++ is with [emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/). The components you mention are all components, but emscripten is a full toolchain that supports building end-to-end, and includes all the parts you need including libc/libc++, and a variety of other useful libraries. It supports targeting both asm.js and wasm.

Comment: This is a good advice in general - it's much easier to build using emscripten - but not at all for this question. Emscripten will create orders of magnitude bigger file than the steps before

Comment: @KarelBílek This may have been true when this answer was posted but it is no longer. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answers in this thread, I've created a little [guide](https://medium.com/@tdeniffel/pragmatic-compiling-from-c-to-webassembly-a-guide-a496cc5954b8).

For me, the easiest way was to compile [emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) (the website is also a great starting point!) on my machine, compile the code to wasm, generate the appropriate bindings and hide all this in a wrapper on the JS-Side to that I get a nice interface.

Because of the name mangling of c++, I've found getting started with C is easier.

Answer (score 2):

A little late for this answer but there are beautiful tools online for compiling your scripts.

By example, I'm using this one. That one giving you minimim option of compiling (C,C++,std99...) but there are sufficient : https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/

And depending of how you gonna use it, you can choose between differents languages such as x86, code Buffer. You can also share your code, kind of functions that I find cool when you are working with some other buddy : https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/?gus9d :)

Comment: This is interesting, but not a realistic option when building entire projects. I need something that can be run locally and on a CI server.