# WebAssembly: TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Imports argument must be present

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm trying to get up to speed with WebAssembly, relying mostly on [WebAssembly developer's guide](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) and a recent [JSConf talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bac0dGQbUto). I can compile a token hello world program, and I can view the generated HTML page to view the result. So far so good.

The issue: The JSConf talk at [18:22](https://youtu.be/bac0dGQbUto?t=18m22s) suggests I can fetch the wasm file, get an array buffer from the response, then instantiate from the buffer, and I should get a promise back. But when I try that -- whether in latest Chrome stable, or Chrome canary, or latest Firefox -- I instead get a [type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNRXB.jpg).

The error message seems to say I need the second, "importObject" argument, even though the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate) says this argument is optional. And what's worse is the MDN page barely talks about the structure and contents of that importObject. I've been able to scrape together some ideas from googling for blogs and github issues. It looks like I may need an "env" key and a WebAssembly memory object?

So... Why is the import object required even though it's documented as being optional? Where can I find detailed documentation for the import object? Why does it work in the JSConf talk but not for me?

Comment: Some hints why the import object is required: Think about how printf is able to print to stdout in this case console.log. The wasm runtime does not reimplement whats already available in the browser. When compiling with emscripten, it adds the required imports automatically. Mostly refered as "emscripten glue code". To understand this issue better look for WASM SIDE_MODULE. 
Standalone: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly-Standalone  
imports: http://webassembly.org/docs/modules/#imports

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295339/can-i-somehow-build-webassembly-code-without-the-emscripten-glue

Answer (score 4):

The import object can be omitted only if the module you instantiate does not import anything. Otherwise, you need to provide an object containing all the required imports. For example, if the module does

```
(import "a" "f" (func ...))
(import "a" "g" (func ...))
(import "b" "m" (memory 0))
```

then you need to provide an import object like

```
{
  a: {f: function (...) { ... }, g: function (...) {...}},
  b: {m: new WebAssembly.Memory(...)}
}
```

Of course, the actual import values can also be predefined objects, or more interestingly exports from another Wasm instance.

Comment: Is there somewhere to find more in-depth documentation about the import object? Or more examples? Thanks :)