# How to use WebAssembly from node.js?

Tags: node.js, emscripten, webassembly

I am currently working on a personal Node.js (>=8.0.0) project which requires me to call C subroutines (to improve execution time). I am trying to use WebAssembly to do this since I need my final code to be compatible when opened in a browser.

I have used Emscripten to compile C code into WebAssembly, and do not know how to proceed after this.

Any help in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can build a .wasm file ([standalone](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly-Standalone)) without JS glue file. Someone has answered the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295339/can-i-somehow-build-webassembly-code-without-the-emscripten-glue).

Create a test.c file:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Build the standalone .wasm file:

```
emcc test.c -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o test.wasm
```

Use the .wasm file in Node.js app:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
var source = fs.readFileSync('./test.wasm');
const env = {
    memoryBase: 0,
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
      initial: 256
    }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({
      initial: 0,
      element: 'anyfunc'
    })
  }

var typedArray = new Uint8Array(source);

WebAssembly.instantiate(typedArray, {
  env: env
}).then(result => {
  console.log(util.inspect(result, true, 0));
  console.log(result.instance.exports._add(9, 9));
}).catch(e => {
  // error caught
  console.log(e);
});
```

The key part is the second parameter of [WebAssembly.instantiate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate). Without it, you will get the error message:

> TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Imports argument must be present
>   and must be an object
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

Comment: Although I figured out the answer a couple of days ago, your answer helped me understand better. Thanks!

Comment: Getting `LinkError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Import #0 module="env" function="__memory_base" error: global import must be a number`

Comment: The example don't work with node 10.x and 8.91. and emcc 1.38.21. Same error as @JBaczuk:
`LinkError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Import #0 module="env" function="__memory_base" error: global import must be a number`

Comment: Found the problem:
test.c
    
    #include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
    int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE add(int a, int b)
    {
       return a+b;
    }
    
Node.js app: replace `memoryBase` with `__memory_base`

Comment: With node 8.93 I get LinkError: WebAssembly Instantiation: table import 0 is smaller than minimum 2, got 0

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @sven. ( translate only )

test.c:

```
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

compiling:

```
emcc test.c -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o test.wasm
```

test.js:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
var source = fs.readFileSync('./test.wasm');
const env = {
  __memory_base: 0,
  tableBase: 0,
  memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
    initial: 256
  }),
  table: new WebAssembly.Table({
    initial: 0,
    element: 'anyfunc'
  })
}

var typedArray = new Uint8Array(source);

WebAssembly.instantiate(typedArray, {
  env: env
}).then(result => {
  console.log(util.inspect(result, true, 0));
  console.log(result.instance.exports._add(10, 9));
}).catch(e => {
  // error caught
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with c++ instead of c?

Comment: Excuse me. I left C aside and went to Golang. Golang becomes webassembly very easy

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly

https://stdiopt.github.io/gowasm-experiments/hexy/