# How to use WebAssembly with Node.js

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I got this code from stackoverflow link:

[How to use WebAssembly from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403326/how-to-use-webassembly-from-node-js)

Create a test.c file:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Build the standalone .wasm file

```
emcc test.c -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o test.wasm
```

Use the .wasm file in Node.js app:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
var source = fs.readFileSync('./test.wasm');
const env = {
    memoryBase: 0,
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
      initial: 256
    }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({
      initial: 0,
      element: 'anyfunc'
    })
  }

var typedArray = new Uint8Array(source);

WebAssembly.instantiate(typedArray, {
  env: env
}).then(result => {
  console.log(util.inspect(result, true, 0));
  console.log(result.instance.exports._add(9, 9));
}).catch(e => {
  // error caught
  console.log(e);
});
```

Receiving error when starting Node.js server with

```
node Node.js
```

LinkError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Import #3 module="env" function="abort" error: function import requires a callable

Answer (score 2):

Loading an emscripten-generated SIDE_MODULE using your own custom code is going to be tricky, because the module you built with emscripten expects to be hosts by emscripten-generated JavaScript.  If order to make it work you will need to provide a compatible environment.   If might be easier to drop the SIDE_MODULE and have emscripten output the js module for you with `-o <something>.js` which will generate both wasm file and a js file that loads it.

If you do want to continue to hand-write your loading code it looks like the first thing you need to do is private and implementation of the `abort` function in the `env` you pass to instantiate.   There will most likely be other functions you need too, and this interface could change as emscripten evolves.