# Node.js webassembly isn't working when compiling c++

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I have read another stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403326/how-to-use-webassembly-from-node-js), which was using c instead of c++. I am using c++, but when I try to follow these procedures except instead of `emcc` i use `em++` to build the wasm, it doesn't allow me to access the function. Suprisingly, when using a regular c file, it works.  cm++

EDIT:

the command I am using to build the wasm file is

```
em++ -O2 test.cpp -o test.wasm -s WASM=1
```

EDIT 2:

I have discovered that emcc also works to build wasm from c++. I have used this command:

```
emcc -O2 test.cpp -o test.wasm -s WASM=1
```

but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the post you are following, the function is `add`. If you replace `result.instance.exports._add` with `result.instance.exports._Z3addii` it will work.